# How to control firefox to open a URL with sending a POST request?

Tags: linux, http, firefox, post

Here is my question. I have a site whose IP is 192.168.80.180. I want to use firefox  to open it. and at the same time sending it a POST request to login. So I don't need to input the username and password in the web page and when firefox is startup it will directly login to the website. My platform is Linux. Please give me some ideas.

Update:
Concretely, how to communicate with firefox ,and let it load a certain URL which is a dynamic page.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm

curl allow you to do requests on anywebsite.

Comment: yeah, I know curl can do this job. But I need to use a browser, I have to show the result for the user.