# Is it possible to open URL from app with POST params to it in Qt?

Tags: qt, http, url, query-string

I need to open link in browser and send to it login and password. Now I do it by this:

```
QUrlQuery urlQuery;
urlQuery.addQueryItem(commonFields_[COMMON_FIELD_USER], Config::getInstance().login());
urlQuery.addQueryItem(commonFields_[COMMON_FIELD_PASSWORD], Config::getInstance().password());

QUrl url = QUrl(Config::getInstance().service() +
                webSuffixes_[WEB_SUFFIX_CREATE_ALBUM_PAGE]);
url.setQuery(urlQuery);

QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
```

But problem that login and password is visible in address fields as GET query string. Is it possible to open URL and POST this parameters?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722685/how-to-control-firefox-to-open-a-url-with-sending-a-post-request

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210900/how-to-pass-post-parameters-in-a-url